# Flutter - select and image from device gallery or take a picture from camera

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-image, flutter-image-picker

I'm implementing a screen to upload an image to my server. I'm looking to create a screen that looks something like this:
[Image pick screen wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrveP.png)

The idea is that you are able to either select an image from your gallery (just one at a time) or use the camera if you prefer. When selecting from your galery it should let you crop the image the way you want on the top part of it. When selecting from the camera the idea is to click on the camera square, open your camera , take the picture and then crop it. After all this i'll send it to my java server inside the body of a post petition.

My problem is that the most used package on the internet for a flutter widget to pick an image from galery or camera is flutter package [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker). Almost all of the tutorials I've found on this package usually aim to make a widget that looks somthing like this:
[Image picker package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUr64.png)
As you can see they usually show 2 buttons that let you selct your source, take a picture or select it from your gallery and then display the image your selected on the secreen.

I'm sure that there has to bee some package similar to what im describing or some internet tutorial on how to build it but i haven't found it. I've seen the package [insta_assets_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/insta_assets_picker) which is kind of similar to what i want but it doesn't allow for you to take a picture from the camera and then crop it. It is important that the solution works both for iOS and Android.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.